# python printing everyword, why?

Tags: python

I'm making one script for DNS transfer, but when I'm entering the info, it gives me following error.
And secondly, when I'm removing `r={}`
I'm getting following error. Please help me, as I'm learning, so I'm slow in this.

```
host: couldn't get address for 'm': not found                                                                                            
e                                                                                                                                        
host: couldn't get address for 'e': not found                                                                                            
g
host: couldn't get address for 'g': not found
a
host: couldn't get address for 'a': not found
c
host: couldn't get address for 'c': not found
o
host: couldn't get address for 'o': not found
r
host: couldn't get address for 'r': not found
p
host: couldn't get address for 'p': not found
o
host: couldn't get address for 'o': not found
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

domain = raw_input("Enter you're domain: ")

host = subprocess.Popen(['host','-t','ns',domain],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]


result=host
r={}
for i in r:
    print i

    zt = subprocess.Popen(['host','-l',domain,i],   stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

print zt
```

```
  ============================
 Enter you're domain: google.com
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./dns-zone.py", line 17, in <module>
  print zt
 NameError: name 'zt' is not defined
```

Comment: You probably need to indent the last line (`print zt`) so that it is inside the forloop.

Comment: Hi Ralf can you tell me why im getting that error? The first one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

domain = raw_input("Enter you're domain: ")
host = subprocess.Popen(['host','-t','ns',domain],  stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
result=host
r={}
for i in r.keys():
    #print i #This is the culprit right here
    zt = subprocess.Popen(['host','-l',domain,i],   stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

print zt
```

You have a print statement in your for loop, so every time it loops it's printing whatever `i` is.  Furthermore, make sure `print zt` is properly tabbed outside of the loop.

Also, it would appear `i` is only a single letter, and not a string like you might need it to be.  Is there more to this code than you're showing?  What exactly is `r = {}` being filled with? Do you perhaps need to do `for i in r.keys()` to iterate properly?

Comment: What exactly is inside `r={}` when the process is running and what are you trying to iterate over? The keys or values?  If keys, use `r.keys()`

Comment: After my host run’s.It gives 3 output, so i want to put the output into empty place, from there i want to put that in zt, so the step can execute that 2nd cmd.